# Solidity getter function returning "undefined" while trying to get value using Ethersjs

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have defined a getter function in my contract which returns value from the nested mapping(public variable).
While trying to get the value using ethersjs, it is returning me undefined even after updating the nested mapping.

Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Profile {
    // state variable
    mapping(address => string[3]) public address_name_imgHash_bio;

function updateName(string memory _name) external {
    address_name_imgHash_bio[msg.sender][0] = _name;
}

function updateImg(string calldata _imgHash) external {
    address_name_imgHash_bio[msg.sender][1] = _imgHash;
}

function updateBio(string calldata _bio) external {
    address_name_imgHash_bio[msg.sender][2] = _bio;
}

// getter
function getter(uint index) external view returns(string memory) {
    return address_name_imgHash_bio[msg.sender][index];
}
}
```

Ethersjs code:

```
let Profile_name

async function updateName(name) {
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const Profile_contract = new ethers.Contract(ProfileAddress, Profile.abi, signer)

        await Profile_contract.updateName(name)
        Profile_name = await Profile_contract.getter(0)
        console.log(Profile_name)
    }
```

On calling `updateName()`, the transaction is successful, but `Profile_name` remains undefined. (I am using hardhat localhost node)
I have verified `ProfileAddress`, `Profile.abi` parameters

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the contract works on remix. therefore the problem is in your script. why is Profile_name a const :/ ?

Comment: Yea, i guess the same. Sorry i wrote const here, have used let in main script.
Can you tell how usually we call a view function using ethersjs?

Comment: https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-contract.html#connecting-to-a-contract it looks okay. no idea what is the problem

Comment: try this please: let tx = await Profile_contract.updateName(name);
console.log(tx.hash);
await tx.wait();
Profile_name = await Profile_contract.getter(0);
console.log(Profile_name);

Comment: Profile_name is showing the value in console, but it is showing undefined when used outside the updateName function. (Profile_name is defined outside the updateName function scope)

Comment: add more details how are you calling it and show more code from the script. I have no ideas but maybe someone else will find the error

Comment: Since the value of `Profile_name` is updated in an async manner then it is possible that you are trying to access it before the value is populated, given you have properly setup scoping of your variable.

Comment: I found the solution. The Profile_name is defined using let (which should not be a problem). But when I define it as a State it's getting updated and not giving any errors.
Thanks a lot for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, in my code I have defined `Profile_name` as `let Profile_name`

But when I tried defining it as a State variable it worked.

```
const[Profile_name, setProfile_name] = useState('')
async function updateName(name) {
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const Profile_contract = new ethers.Contract(ProfileAddress, Profile.abi, signer)

        await Profile_contract.updateName(name)
        output = await Profile_contract.getter(0)
        setProfile_name(output) // assigning
        console.log(Profile_name)
    }
```